# error when capturing camera and audio input

Tags: iphone, video, ios4, video-streaming, video-capture

using some of the nifty new APIs in iOS4 i am trying to capture input from the iPhone's camera and microphone and save it to a file. below is the code i am using.

```
AVCaptureSession* captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];
AVCaptureDeviceInput* videoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:captDevice error:&error];
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput * videoOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

if (videoInput && videoOutput && audioInput) 
{
    [captureSession addInput:audioInput];
    [captureSession addInput:videoInput];
    [captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];
    if([captDevice lockForConfiguration:&error])
    {
        if ([captDevice hasTorch]) 
            captDevice.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOn;

        [captDevice unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not lock device for config error: %@", error);
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL* saveLocationURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/movie.mov", documentsDirectory]];

    [videoOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:saveLocationURL recordingDelegate:self];
    [captureSession startRunning];

    [saveLocationURL release];
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Video Error: %@", error);
}
```

when the didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL comes back i get a cryptic error response.

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11803 "Cannot Record" UserInfo=0x152f70 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try recording again., AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=false, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Record}
```

the error code −11803 means "AVErrorSessionNotRunning". all i can say is tell me something i don't know. anyone have any idea why the session is not running?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call `[captureSession startRunning];` before `[videoOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:saveLocationURL recordingDelegate:self];`.

Comment: that fixed the reported problem but now i get a new error.

Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12673 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12673.)" UserInfo=0x154190 {AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=false}

Comment: Does movie.mov already exist? See also "stringByAppendingPathComponent:".

Comment: I just thought maybe it would refuse to overwrite an existing file. Where is `captDevice` initialized?

Comment: Did you ever discover the meaning of this "OSStatus error -12673." problem? I am having the same error.

Comment: @Meekohi: I ran into the -12673 error as well, and it was caused by trying to write the file to an unwritable location. Once wrote to a directory that I knew was writable, using NSTemporaryDirectory(), the capture worked. I constructed the file URL like [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/video.mov", NSTemporaryDirectory()]].